# "mail" function in PHP not recognized

Tags: php, email, sms

I am trying to send an text message using PHP, what I am doing is using the mail function to send a message to the phone number at the carrier domain. Take a look:

```
<?php
$to = 'numbers@vtext.com';
$subject = 'subject';
$message = 'test';
$headers = 'From: RJ';
bool mail ( string $to, 
    string $subject, 
    string $message
    string $headers) //sends text message?
?>
```

I try to run the program, but it gives me a syntax error, saying that Mail is not a function.

Notes: I am using WAMP server, I have smtp, ssl_module and php_sockets all enabled, as said to do by tutorial I found.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't how you call a function, this is how you declare a function definition:

```
bool mail ( string $to, 
    string $subject, 
    string $message
    string $headers)
```

It looks like you want to actually *call* the function, like this:

```
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

Comment: This is what I was going to say; except I would also add removing the headers if possible; just in case they cause issue.  I believe they are optional.

Comment: The error I am getting is- "( ! ) Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'mail' (T_STRING) in D:\wamp\www\smsTest.php on line 6"

Comment: @Owlman: Are you sure the code posted is the *exact* code you're using?  If that's the case then there's something wrong with your PHP because the `mail()` function should definitely exist.

Comment: The only thing I am altering is the $to= for to not put my phone number online.